# Ищу dataframe картинок для обучения с нейросетью

Tags: dataframe, искусственный-интеллект, neuralbase

Хочу создать ИИ с нейросетью для определения по камере надет ли человека ремень безопасности или нет. Но для обучения нужны картинки. Где можно найти картинки конкретно для моей задачи?

Comment: Традиционно советую подписаться на слак сообщества ods.ai, там на все data science темы есть форумы, датасеты с картинками там тоже можно найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте kaggle попробуй поискать

Comment: Ответ подразумевает точное знание, а не предположения. Предположения в комментарии включают.